# SQL Server Bulk Insert Http file

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert a csv file located on a remote web server but i am getting the following error.

> Cannot bulk load because the file "http://34.34.32.34/test.csv" could
>   not be opened. Operating system error code 123(The filename, directory
>   name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: What happens if you go to `http://34.34.32.34/test.csv` in a webbrowser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `BULK INSERT` says nothing about SQL Server being able to connect to web servers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

> ' data_file ' Is the full path of the data file that contains data to
>   import into the specified table or view. BULK INSERT can import data
>   from a disk (including network, floppy disk, hard disk, and so on).
>
> data_file must specify a valid path from the server on which SQL
>   Server is running. If data_file is a remote file, specify the
>   Universal Naming Convention (UNC) name. A UNC name has the form
>   \Systemname\ShareName\Path\FileName. For example,
>   \SystemX\DiskZ\Sales\update.txt.

If you *must* import a file from HTTP, consider writing a CLR stored procedure or using SSIS' external connectivity capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

`http://34.34.32.34/test.csv` is, exactly as the error message says, an incorrect file name. Correct filenames look like `c:\somefolder\test.csv`. Something that starts with `http:` is an [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), not a file.

[BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) does not support URLs as source. You should download the file first locally (using [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget), [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) or any other program that can download HTTP content), then bulk insert the downloaded file.